# Question of the Week #35

Tags: discussion, status-deferred, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 35 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ## [What is the purpose of the holes marked "Do Not Cover" on hard drives?](https://superuser.com/questions/368774/do-not-cover-this-hole)
>
> On many hard drives, there's a text warning to "not cover this hole", sometimes adding that doing so will void the warranty.
> What is the purpose of this hole and why would it cause damage or increase the likelihood of drive failure?

Comment: I've always wondered about that...would be a good blog post

Comment: Speaking of Blog  I still want to know why they dont go with a (partial) Vaccume in the drive, it would reduce friction, reduce oxidation, and moisture entry.  The only thing I could come up with , it still needs the Air movement, the "wind" because particles that come off of the head and platters, gets splattered into another filter??  I cannot see where it would be a problem with "altitude", decompressed cargo accidents, heat, expansion/contraction or any reason why they dont?

Comment: I'll write about this eventually. I think.

Answer (score 4):

[Scenario - NTFS Symbolic Link or Junction?](https://superuser.com/q/366116/24500)

I like this one. Outside of SU, there are a lot of questions about Symlinks, Hardlinks and Junctions and their differences and possible uses.

Answer (score 3):

[Does a computer use fewer resources when programs are minimized?](https://superuser.com/q/364949/101850)

When programs are minimized in Windows 7, do they use less memory and CPU than leaving them maximized?

Answer (score 0):

> ## [Why don't you see binary code when you open a binary file with text editor?](https://superuser.com/questions/369231/why-you-dont-see-binary-code-when-you-open-binary-file-with-text-editor)
>
> Why you don't see binary code when you open binary file with text editor? For example when I open image with text editor I see some weird characters and also some human readable characters. But image should be encoded in binary.